# How can I sort pandas series by using sort_values() but without using natsort?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have one csv file-

```
data = pd.read_csv('New_Region.csv') 
data = data.squeeze() 
data
```

output is-

```
0     Region 3
1    Region 11
2     Region 5
3     Region 1
4     Region 8
5    Region 10
6    Region 13
7     Region 2
Name: Region, dtype: object
```

Now I want to sort the data in ascending way and my expected output is-

```
3     Region 1
7     Region 2
0     Region 3
2     Region 5
4     Region 8
5    Region 10
1    Region 11
6    Region 13
Name: Region, dtype: object
```

I already got the solution by using natsort.
But can I get this output using `sort_values()` but without using the Natsort module?